# Align some items flex-start and other flex-end with dynamic space in between?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container where I want the first two items vertically aligned to the top and the last two items vertically aligned to the bottom.

The first two items are assigned `align-self: flex-start;`
The last two items are assigned `align-self: flex-end;`

What property do I need to set to the container to ensure that the 'purple gap' below is only displaying in the middle between the two sets of elements (ie; below the 'test short desc' and above the 'ul dropdown title 1'?

[image]

Comment: You should share your HTML and CSS if you really want exact help. But as a general rule of thumb if you only want to have a single space between those 2 sets of elements then you should put the button inside the same containing element as the UL dropdown. If you don't have a container around the `ul` just add a `div` and put the button after the `ul`.

Comment: Thx, that worked - just wrapped the items into two distinct divs and then spaced between.